# How to Add table association in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a table called User, a table called Permission and an association table so Many Users can have many Permissions.

**User**

ID - PK

**Permission**

ID - PK

**UserPermission**

UserID - PK (FK to user)

PermissionID - PK (FK to Permission)

In entity framework how can I add an entry to the association table to link a user to a permission?

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
var user = _Repository.Users.Single(u => u.ID == someUserID);
var permission = _Repository.Permissions.Single(p => p.ID == somePermissionID);

user.Permissions.Add(permission) //Not working
user.Permission.Attach(permission) //Still not working

_Repository.Save();
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
UserPermission obj = new UserPermission { UserID = someUserID, PermissionID = somePermissionID };
_Repository.UserPermissions.AddObject(obj)
_Repository.Save();
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I dont think this will work, Entity Framework ignores my table association and treats it as a navigation. So I dont have access to the Association table

Comment: It is because the association table has only two fields which are related to their parent table, that why it is not showing in you edmx file. But it still consists in the designer.cs file. You will definitely found **UserPermissions** in intellisense.

Comment: I have done a search for the Table in the Entity Framework Designer.cs and there is no class for the association table

Comment: @AndyClark, what is the definition of **_Repository.Save();** method?

Comment: Save any pending changes to the database, this is being done using a repository pattern

Comment: does you _Repository have another Data Context?

Comment: No, just one context to every table in the database. Just not the table associations obviously. The scenario you described will work in LINQ to SQL as it will include the UserPermission table. But in my case I will have to figure something out with the navigation property as I am using Entity Framework

Comment: the save method consists of one line 
`_Context.SaveChanges();`

Comment: okay and what does _Repository object when you were using "_Repository.Users.Single(u => u.ID == someUserID);" Is it returning the same _Context ?

Comment: Yes, my repository only has one context and uses this context for every database interaction

Comment: @AndyClark, if this so than your code will definitely work. Try check or provide the code of _Repository so that i can rectify where is the problem is?